# preg_replace tags between tags

Tags: php

Im trying to replace html tags that are between pre tags. This is what I want it to do:

```
$str = '<pre><div>Get<p>rid</p> of html tags</div></pre>';
$str = preg_replace('#(<pre.*?>)/<[^<>]+>/(</pre>)#', '$1$2', $str);
echo $str;
```

It should responed with, "Get rid of html tags" in pre tags

I know for a fact that,

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<pre.*?>).*?(</pre>)#', '$1$2', $str);
```

works, but responds with empty pre tags.

I just need to remove all html tags in between the pre tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("#(<pre[^>]*>).*?</pre>#is",function($m) {
    return $m[1].strip_tags($m[0])."</pre>";
},$str);
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I would of came on here earlier, would of saved me 5 hours :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<pre><div>Get<p>rid</p> of html tags</div></pre>';
if(preg_match("/<pre>(.+?)<\/pre>/i", $str,$res))
{
  $str=strip_tags($res[1]);
}
echo $str;
```